# Are there any graph embedding algorithms like this already?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, graph, data-science

Note: This question is a copy of the original question [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/63482/are-there-any-graph-embedding-algorithms-like-this-already), because I suspect that datascience stack exchange platform may be just not developed and popular enough for the answer to be found there.

I wrote an [algorithm](https://github.com/monomonedula/simple-graph-embedding) for generating node embeddings based on the graph's topology. Most of the explanation is done in the readme file and the examples.

The question is:
Am I reinventing the wheel?
Does this approach have any practical advantages over existing solutions for embeddings generation?

Yes, I'm aware there are many algorithms for this based on random walks, but this one is pure deterministic linear algebra and it is quite simple, from my perspective.

In short, the algorithm is heavily inspired by PageRank.
Every node is described by its proximity vector which contains the node's closeness number to every other node or some selected subset of the nodes.
The "closeness" is not just the simple shortest distance.

Here's brief explanation from the repo's readme for directed/undirected unweighted graph (the idea generalizes to weighted graphs pretty intuitively):

1. Every node is assigned a vector. For node i the vector's j-th element is a number representing its closeness to node j (you can think of it as signal strength).
2. The closeness of the node i to the node j (the "central" node the signal flows from) is defined as a sum of the signal strengths of the neighboring nodes multiplied by the damping factor parameter. (The dumping factor works like a kind of distance penalty)
3. Signal a node "emits" to other connected nodes equal to the given signal's strength in the node itself divided by the number of edges it is able to emit to.
4. Initially, the node j is assigned a closeness (to itself) equal to 1.

The whole thing is computed by solving sparse linear systems.

"Signal" strengths from node 4 to other nodes. Note that the signal here travel in direction opposite to edge direction (like "follow" relation on Instagram)

[image: "Signal" strengths from node 4 to other nodes. Note that the signal here travel in direction opposite to edge direction (like "follow" relation on Instagram)]

Comment: Why this is tagged python?

Comment: @DanielMesejo because the implementation of the algorithm is written in python

Comment: As an alternative to stackoverflow, have you considered the [computer science stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), or even the [mathematics stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/), since this is a fundamentally mathematical problem?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what your algorithm is trying to do - you've explained broadly how the algorithm works, but you have not specified the problem it's supposed to solve very clearly. A clearer description of the problem is needed to know whether or not you are "reinventing the wheel".

Comment: @kaya3 what's so unclear about "algorithm for generating node embeddings based on the graph's topology"?

Comment: In mathematics, "graph embedding" means drawing a graph on a surface with no edges crossing each other. It's not clear if that's what you're talking about because generally the term is used to refer to arbitrary two-dimensional surfaces or manifolds. The problem of "embedding" a graph in a 2D plane is usually called "graph drawing", and generally it's preferable to minimise edge-crossings but they aren't forbidden (because many graphs are non-planar). Your question doesn't mention whether or not edge-crossings are allowed, for example.

Comment: I also thought it was possible that since some of your nodes are coloured differently, you might be referring to embedding one graph as a subgraph of another graph. That would be a rather different problem too.